# AWS: Calling Cognito.sign_up from Lambda times out

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-vpc

I suspect this might be IAM/VPC issue but perhaps not? My Lambda function calls Cognito's `sign_up` to register. The lambda function is behind an API GET endpoint.

I am able to call the endpoint locally and it creates the Cognito user successfully. However, when I deploy it to a staging environment, it doesn't seem to be able to call Cognito anymore. I peeked at the Cloudwatch logs and there is no error reported.

Staging environment has a lambda function behind a VPC that also has a MySQL database as well. I am able to pull data from this database from this lambda function. From that same environment, I am now trying to call Cognito user pool.

I also checked that the permission IAM role for this lambda function has `CognitoPowerUser` permissions.

I am not sure what other IAM roles/permissions I am missing here, it seems to work fine when I call it locally but not from the said staging environment.

Comment: It's not an IAM problem. It's likely to be networking. If your Lambda function is connected to a VPC then it will need a network route to the Cognito API endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption would also be that this is an issue with your Lambda function in the VPC being unable to reach the public internet due to your VPC set up.

I would encourage you to review this blog to ensure you are set up correctly from a network perspective.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/